# JSF2 custom component, parameter autocompletion with a local file path

Tags: intellij-idea, jsf-2, filepath, custom-component, uiinclude

My First Question, after years, thank you all and stackoverflow ;-)

I code a new Component for JSF2 and use it to include other templates.
It works perfectly for me.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="src" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="addOption" type="java.util.List"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <cc:insertChildren />
    <ui:include src="#{BeanAnything.convert(cc.attrs.src, cc.attrs.addOption)}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

But i cant complete the Parameter src via auto completion in intellij or netbeans with "strg + space" or whatever other will use.
It should be used like the `ui:include` on src parameter.

Any Ideas ?
That's what I want to achieve only with my own componente `gg:include`
[See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko2jw.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Do you mean you don't get the parameter name itself autocompleted?

Comment: i mean a suggestion of projectFiles to this parameter.
The parameter itself is just a string, as with ui:include.

Comment: I know, but you mean for example the `addOption` text being autocompleted when you use your custom component? I don't get it clearly from the question.

Comment: Oh sorry that's a bit incomprehensible.
When I use the components, I call them up with `<gg:include src="fragments/xyz.xhtml" />`.
The content of the parameter src should then only be used by autocomplete for local files. The add option can be completely ignored here.

Comment: So you mean the value autocompletion with a local file path.. You could edit the question title for better understanding.